# ¿Cómo obtener la duración de ejecución de una query Mysql y PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Al ejecutar una query en phpmyadmin nos da `... (Query took 0.0017 seconds).`, ¿hay algún modo de obtener ese dato `0.0017` a partir de una query Mysql? Me gustaría incluirlo en mi página cuando se realiza una búsqueda.

Me gustaría hacer algo así:

```
SELECT id, ..., DuracionDeEjecutarLaQuery FROM tabla WHERE 1
```

Para posteriormente incluiro en mi código PHP:

```
...
$duracion = $row -> DuracionDeEjecutarLaQuery;
...
```

Si es imposible lo que yo quiero, alguna alternativa como por ejemplo: la duración de que la página sea cargada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La idea es hacer tú mismo dicho cálculo. Es decir, cogiendo la fecha actual antes de la query y lo mismo justo después de la query, como si crearas una traza. Básicamente puedes hacerlo de 2 formas:

SQL:

```
DECLARE 
   antes   DATETIME,
   despues DATETIME
SET antes = SYSDATE
-- AQUI HACES TU QUERY...
SET despues = SYSDATE

SELECT ANTES - DESP FROM DUAL; -- Hacemos la resta
```

o desde `PHP` usando la función [`Date`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

Comment: Gracias, me resuelve el problema :)